# Login Page with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, login-page

Im making a login page with spring boot but it doesnt seem to be working. I cant login to my page. i checked all the codes multiple times, no error messages appear. I just dont know what the problem is.

here are of the code I wrote

```
@Controller
public class MusicrewPageController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("login")
    public String showList(Authentication loginUser, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(" username", loginUser.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute(" authority", loginUser.getPassword());
        return "user";
    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/memberRegirstration", "/css/**", "/images/**")
                        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/top")
                        .permitAll())
                .rememberMe();
        return http.build();

    }
    
}
```

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userReposiroty;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userReposiroty.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String surName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String surNameKana;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String firstNameKana;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    @Size(max = 254)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 60)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 60)
    private String pass;

    private String gender;

    private String birthday;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return "User.getUsername()";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "User.getPassword()";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String Username);

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Musicrew Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/login.css}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <img th:src="@{images/loginpage.jpg}">

        <div id="login-page-rightside">
            <img th:src="@{images/MusicrewLogo.png}">
            <div>
                <form id="form" th:action="@{/top}" method="post" >
                    <label class="label-username">username</label>
                    <input class="text-box" type="text" name="username">

                    <label class="label-password">password</label>
                    <input class="text-box" type="password" name="password"><br>

                    <input class="remember-me" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="remember-me">remember me</label>
                    
                    <label class="forget-password">パスワードを忘れた方はこちら</label><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="login" id="login-button">
                    <br>
                </form>

                <form th:action="@{/memberRegistration}" id="form">
                    <input type="submit" value="sign up" id="signup-button">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Urak4812Urak4812
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

since there was no error message, i didnt know which erroe to search. I watched videos and read articles regarding how to make a login page, but i seem to not find the problem

Comment: this is different `/memberRegistration` in html and `/memberRegirstration` in `SecurityConfig`

Comment: Can you share what exactly problem you are facing it means if web page is not displaying then problem should be in view or HTML side. If page is displaying but action not forwarded then problem is in back-end. So if you specify then anyone can help you better

Comment: What about front? {/memberRegistration} where is host and port to backend? Was it written in properties? Check your front response of request, what is the result of request

Comment: @SatyajitBhatt The login page is displayed fine, but when i clicck on login it shows an erros. and for the error messages not showing, Im sorry I missed it. it was written              org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [user], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers